# Create indicator variable for NA values in a dataframe using index values for larger dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with around 300 features and 1million observations. I have created a list variable with has the index values that contain 80% of data  as NA values.

My index list has -> 2,4
I want to create an indicator variable for the columns with index 2 ,3 of dataframe to replace NA values with "0" and other values in the column with "1"

I tried to loop through each row but as data is huge its taking long time to loop it.

Input dataframe -> df

row        **col1**     col2      **col3**
a          **NA**      1        **3**
a        **NA**      1       **NA**
a        **2**     2     **NA**

Expected output:
row        **col1**     col2      **col3**
a          **0**      1        **1**
a        **0**      1       **0**
a        **1**     2     **0**

Can anyone point me to the right direction to achieve this faster.

Thanks,
Renuka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::mutate_at` to select the columns you want to change then apply a `case_when` function to recode NAs as 0 and anything else as 1 which should be a lot quicker than a for loop.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%  
  mutate_at(vars(col1, col3), funs(
    case_when(
      is.na(.) ~ 0,
      TRUE ~ 1
  )))
```